# Is there thought and emotion component for psychic spells?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, spell-components, occult-magic, psychic-class

I could have sworn that psychic spells had there specific components listed like regular spells. For example, the fireball spell tells you the material component is bat guano.

I seem to remember seeing what you had to think of and what emotions you had to focus on specifically to cast a psychic spell.

Answer (score 8):

### You're Somewhat Misremembering

Psychic spells do have thought and emotion components, but I don't believe they're actually listed directly on any spells. Even Psychic only spells, like [Mind Thrust](https://aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Mind%20Thrust%20I) list the standard components rather than the ones for Psychic Magic.

Instead to determine what components a spells has for Psychic Magic, we need to look at the [rules for it](https://www.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Components&Category=Psychic%20Magic):

> Instead of verbal and somatic components, all psychic spells have components related to the caster’s inner being. The two psychic components are called emotion components and thought components. If a spell’s components line lists a somatic component, that spell instead requires an emotion component when cast by psychic spellcasters, and if it has a verbal component, it instead requires a thought component when cast by psychic spellcasters. Psychic spells cast by non-psychic arcane and divine casters use any listed somatic and verbal components as normal.

Essentially, you'd need to look at the spell's components and then figure out what they'd turn into on your own, for the earlier example of Mind Thrust, it would have an emotion component in place of its somatic one.